# What is the difference between Voltage and Voltage Drop?

Tags: voltage

Voltage is the [electric potential difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage).

Voltage Drop is the [decrease of electrical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_drop).

So what's the difference? Is it that Voltage Drop only refers to a negative voltage?

And is it accurate to say resistors (or other things that cause a voltage drop) have a (negative) voltage?

---

Also, just to be clear that I'm understanding voltage correctly, [this article uses "voltage difference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage#:%7E:text=Voltage%20difference) incorrectly, right? (Since voltage *is* the difference).

Comment: The fact that X is defined as a difference doesn't mean you can't have an "X difference"; a difference of differences is well-defined.

Comment: @Hearth Yeah, I agree - I meant the article used it incorrectly.

Comment: Outside of referring to a difference-of-differences, the specific case of the term "voltage difference" can also be used synonymously with "voltage".

Comment: Huh. That means my question is probably just nitpicking about semantics.

Comment: I am not sure I would say that article is flat out incorrect. But it would be better and more consistent if it said "The potential between points..." instead of "The voltage between points..." I think in engineering circles people would say "the voltage between" this and that. But a physicist might say "the electrical potential" between this and that. Try to keep an open mind and not be too pedantic about it. Unless you want to become a physics professor, in which case it is your job to uphold a high standard for precise language.

Comment: The first link tells it like it is (avoiding gauge theories and keeping it simple -- 1D): \$V_{_\text{A,B}}=\int_{_\text{A}}^{^\text{B}} \mathscr{E}_{_\text{x}}\:\text{d}x\$. To a mathematician, that's all you'd need. It covers node-to-node differences, 'across a resistor' differences, and potentials within a semiconductor structure all equally well. A voltage is never an absolute value recognized by the universe (so far as we know.) It's always a difference between two points in space (or space-time.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Voltage drop" is not a highly technical term defined in precise physical language. It is more like a term used by engineers and technicians.
Broadly speaking, "voltage" is measured with the reference being the ground node (defined as zero volts).
"Voltage drop" is usually measured or defined between two points, neither of which needs to be the ground.

**Usage Examples**
If you are installing an inverter, you may find that the battery voltage is 12.8 V and the input to the inverter is 12.5 V. This means you have a voltage drop of 0.3 V in the wiring.
When you talk about a linear regulator, if the input voltage is 5 V and the output voltage is 3.3 V, then the voltage drop in the regulator or across the regulator is 1.7 V.

Comment: Ohh, so that means voltage is kind of like position - if `x=5`, it's talking about relative to the origin, just like if `voltage=5`, it's talking about relative to ground.

Comment: Another distinction is that "voltage drop" is used only for a circuit where current is flowing. You would probably not refer to the open circuit voltage of a battery as "voltage drop".

Comment: Yeah voltage is like position and voltage drop is like distance. Also I agree with PStechPaul that it doesn't sound right to me to talk about voltage drop when current is not flowing. When you say "voltage drop" you are usually thinking about power loss or power dissipation. Again, not highly scientific. But useful.

Comment: " 'Voltage drop' is usually measured or defined between two points, neither of which is ground." Be careful with the wording. Someone could take this to mean that it can't possibly be a voltage drop if one of the points is ground.

Comment: This terminology sounds a little strange to me. If I have a string of several incandescent lamps in series, connected to an isolated power supply, would you refer to the voltage across one of the lamps as "voltage drop" or as "voltage"?

Comment: @Tanner-reinstateLGBTpeople take your pick. Each lamp has a voltage drop of 10 V. Each lamp has a voltage across it of 10 V. There is 10 V across each lamp. Each lamp feels 10 V. All OK ways to say it.

Comment: @nitro2k01 I felt there were enough qualifiers in there, but someone edited the text so hopefully it is better now.

Answer (score 4):

Voltage drop in this context would be used for the difference between two voltages.

For example, we have two wires running from a 12V battery to  a motor. The wires have resistance. At the battery the voltage (measured from positive terminal to negative terminal) is 12V. At the motor the voltage (measured from the red wire to the black wire) is 10V. We can say there is a voltage drop of 2V (probably 1V per wire if the wires are similar gauge).

As far as negative and positive, that can lead to a lot of confusion. Suppose you have a big hefty ground connection connected to the + terminal of a battery. We run a thin negative wire to a lamp, with the return current through ground. The - terminal of the battery is at -12V wrt ground. The lamp is at -10V wrt ground. So the voltage at the lamp is 2V higher than at the battery. We still say it has a 2V voltage drop though. The magnitude of the voltage is less and there's less available to the load.

Comment: If the battery is 12V, can you say that the motor has -10V and the lamp has -2V voltage? I understand that the voltage +/- is just dependent on perspective, so voltage drop means the magnitude of the voltage decreases, right?

Comment: Since voltage drop across resistances can only cause a decrease we would normally just talk about the magnitude. The lamp has 10V, the motor has 10V, the voltage drop is 2V.  But for most other purposes the polarity can be quite important. If the motor has marked + and - terminals then the voltage wrt ground is not as important as the voltage across those terminals - and it could be measured as 10V (meter red probe on + and black on -) or maybe you'd measure -10V if the motor is running backwards. If it's a heater, the polarity is not important, so it's sufficient to say 10V.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, just to be clear that I'm understanding voltage correctly, there is no such thing as "voltage difference", right? (Since voltage is the difference).

Well, people certainly use that phrase to mean the same thing as the voltage (or potential) difference between two points.  So you probably need to us recognize that it's common usage and not get wound up about it.

Yes, when we say "voltage" we mean *any* potential difference.

When we say "voltage drop" we specifically mean a voltage that decreases in the direction of current flow -- so a voltage drop is something that can happen with a purely passive component, such as a resistor or a wire.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, although the difference would be considered too particular in the minds of some.

*From an entirely technical perspective,* voltage is the difference of potential between two points. Most people who talk about voltage all day don't use it exactly like that though.

A similar concept, velocity is not speed (speed is the magnitude of the velocity vector) and mass isn't weight (weight is the magnitude of the mass vector). A normal person may refer to their mass without giving the direction. They may not like it if you try to correct them.

Just as we use velocity and mass to refer to non-directional values in normal speech, we use voltage to refer to the potential between a single point and ground. It's just easier to conceptualize and talk about that way: "the voltage at this point is 3.3V."

For a long time, circuits were predominantly composed of a source of potential, and various components that had some resistive or reactive Thevenin equivalent. (Many circuits in common use still follow this general idea.) With only one source, each component introduces *voltage drop,* which is negative potential across it. Rather than keep stating that all the potentials are negative, we call the entire result a voltage drop, and we know it's negative.

This usage may also vary greatly with the crowd you're in, such as how precise they are, and whether they're physicists, engineers, electricians, or nurses, and so on.